# Can the iPhone reliably detect fake batteries or are there ways around it?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, repair, third-party

I’m a resident in a developing country with lots of fake products. There’s also no Apple store except in the capital, and the ‘authorized resellers’ may actually still have fake parts. Now I need to replace the battery in my iPhone SE 2020, but I want to make sure it’s not a fake and dangerous battery. If I have the battery replaced here and the iPhone does not warn me that it’s a fake battery, is that actually reliable and can I trust on that to not have the battery explode in my face?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "fake". But I assume there wouldn't be a market for "fake" batteries if an iPhone could easily detect them :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a Service/Repair Provider is genuine before starting

[Apple Authorized Service Providers and Independent Repair Providers](https://support.apple.com/repair/verify-repair-provider)

After the fact, you can check on the phone itself

[iPhone parts and service history](https://support.apple.com/HT212878)

[image][image]

Comment: There are a few genuine stores here, but I have a contacted them and they still don't have the original Apple batteries. Are you saying the non-Apple batteries are still considered 'genuine'? As long as they're of a certain quality?

Comment: No. If a store claims to be genuine, I'd rely on the Apple page rather than the store's say-so. I'd initiate this repair directly with Apple, online. Then you know it will be a genuine replacement part. [It also saves you having to go to the store twice.]

Comment: What does a non-genuine designation look like?